# Rails 3 paper_trail track multiple associated models for undo

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paper-trail-gem

I've been trying for the last few days to use paper_trail as an undo system, where multiple objects can be rolled back at once; I began with the [Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/255-undo-with-paper-trail), and have been trying my best to get something working. I feel like I am close, but also feel like my implementation could be better, or possibly there is a different way that I don't know about or is beyond my skill.

So far I've tried this:
Added a parent_id column to versions. This holds another versions id.
Created a method to set this ID, where after doing a save, update or delete, I pass the parent and child models in and then update that childs latest version's parent_id with the parents latest version id. It looks like this:

```
def set_parent_to_version(parent, child)
    child.versions.last.update_attributes(:parent_id => parent.versions.last.id)
end
```

And then when I make an update that affects more than the parent model, I call this and it updates the just made version of the child model as well.

In my revert method, I then find the version by params[:id] and all children by parent_id params[:id], and reify them all. This work well to an extent.

The problem is with callbacks - I have a callback on a model that, before_destroy, it modifies another model. However, in this case I don't know if the user initiated this destroy or a different model, and so I can't get the parent_id. In other words, Employee has many items, employee destroys items, items modify employee before_destroy. The before_destroy doesn't know why it was destroyed or who did it.

I know the papertrail gem already says it just doesn't work well with associations, but I feel like this must be possible - somehow looking at the callbacks maybe? I might be in too deep on this, but for the actions that the undo works on, it's super nice and I don't want to drop it.

ANY ideas appreciated. Thanks!